# How to access the session from a Background Task in MVC3 (StructureMap)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, structuremap

I am trying to start a long running process in a MVC controller and then immediately return to the user so that they can start another long running process.  I would look at doing this via ajax but I do need to read some values from a physical machine before allowing them to continue which takes less than .3 seconds.  The only problem is that the method in the Task reads values from the Session which is no longer available.   Is there a way to create a HttpContext that has the users Session values for use with StructureMap?

Below is the Task

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task async = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
            {
                var response = service.LongRunningTask(request, weight);
                this.requestCache.Insert("someKey", 120, response);
            });
        async.Start();
```

And this is where the error is happening when the Session is read (SessionWrap just reads a value from the Session)

```
       registry.For<IPrintService>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(() =>
            {
                var profiler = ServiceLocatorManager.Current.Resolve<IProfiler>();
                    return new PrintService(AppSettings.PrintDirectly, SessionWrap.UseLabelPrinter, SessionWrap.UsePrinter, profiler) as IPrintService;
            });
```

Comment: How is your `IPrintService` being requested from your IoC container?

Comment: It is being requested via a constructor argument that is injected into another class.

Comment: Which other class? The reason I ask is that if you're using pure constructor injection I would expect the binding method to be run when the controller is created, and not when you call `service.LongRunningTask`. So accessing the SessionWrapper would happen well before the task gets created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not access any HttpContext intrinsic objects such as Request, Response, Session, ... in background tasks simply because they might be long gone when the task executes. You could aggregate all the information that this task will need inside some model class and pass it to the task before running. This way the task will have everything it needs and it won't be necessary to access the HttpContext.